# EF4.1 CodeFirst: Add field to join table

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am using EF 4.1 RC and CodeFirst/POCO to build my database by code.

Imagine having a many-to-many relationship like Teachers-Students (one teacher can have many students, and one student may have many teachers). Accordingly I have two POCOs: (1) Teacher and (2) Student.

When EF creates the corresponding tables you will end up with three tables: (1)Teachers, (2) Students and (3) an extra join table. The join table contains exactly two fields: a Teacher_ID and a Student_ID.

I was wondering if I had any chance to add an extra field to the join table, e.g. "Grade" (the grade a certain teacher gives a certain teacher)?

Currently I have no idea how to achieve this with only two POCOs.

So I guess all I can do is create a third POCO (for the join table) manually, am I right? That will certainly work, but then I am losing nice navigation properties like oneTeacher.Students.First(), etc. That is the main reason why I am still looking for another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct, and does not only apply to Code-first. If you have extra fields in your joining table, you will have it mapped as an entity. And vice-versa, if you want an extra field in your joining table, you need to create a new entity and have zero-or-one-to many or one-to-many navigation properties to the `Teacher` and `Student` entities. In any case, you lose the comfort of accessing `Teacher.Students` and `Student.Teachers` and have to go via the intermediate entity.

Alternatively, you could think about modeling the DB structure differently and extracting the extra info into the `Teacher` or `Student` or a fourth entity. But that depends entirely on your scenario.

Comment: All right, thanks guys! That is what I thought. Just wanted to go sure I didn't miss some kind of a hidden feature ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the join table cannot have a payload or you need to break it down to 2 one to many association which will result in creating a third entity to hold the PKs as well as the additional properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea I still haven't found time to try it out. Maybe you can keep your Student and Teacher classes as they are, and add a third POCO `StudentGrade` with properties `Student`, `Teacher` and `Grade`. Then you'll have to use the fluent API to make sure that both the many to many relation between `Student` and `Teacher` and the `StudentGrade` class map to the same table.

Hope that helps